# Summation of text fields on keyup causes issues in first field of a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table.I am trying to find out the summation as below:
`td(1) + td(2) + td(3) = td(4)`, `td(5) + td(6) + td(7) = td(8)`, `td(9) + td(10) + td(11) = td(12)`.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').on('keyup', 'input', function () {
        $("#table tr").slice(2).find("td:nth-child(4n + 1)").each(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $(this).prevAll(':lt(3)').find('input').each(function () {
                sum += (+this.value || 0)
            });
            $(this).find('input').val(sum)
        })
    })
})
```

The code above works fine. But my problem is, I can't enter any thing to first column (ie, `td:eq(0)`). Whats wrong with my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/b0svwpnn/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly exclude the first `input` from the `nth-child` selection, which you can achieve using `:not()`. Try this:

```
$("#table tr").slice(2).find("td:nth-child(4n + 1):not(:first)")
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b0svwpnn/4/)